# Where can I find my AWS Application Load Balancer IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I have setup an AWS **Network Load Balancer** no problem and I have a number of different services running on their assigned ports. This all works perfectly.

Then I was asked to host a number of different node apps on their own ports and are accessed via their own domains. After I realised I couldn't get this to work correctly on **NLB** I looked to **Application Load Balancer** and use **Host-Based Routing** rules.

- app1.example.com
- app2.example.com

**What I did**

I setup the application load balancer listener on **https :443** and a **Host-Based Routing** rule that forwards **app1.example.com** traffic to a target group to watch **443** and send the traffic to the correct instance on **port 3000**. The security group is also setup to with **port 3000** open.

So I thought.... all I had to do was add the load balancer IP to the subdomain A Records on the external domain registrar.... but I can't find the IP anywhere! I'm missing something fundamental here and AWS docs are killing me.

The above steps aren't too different from setting up a **Network Load Balancer** without the **Host-Based Routing** rules.

Could anyone point out where I can find the ALB IP or where am I'm going off track?

Comment: AWS ELB/ALB IP addresses may change. Don't use it. This is wrong regardless: `add the load balancer IP to the subdomain A Records on the external domain registrar` add an A record ALIAS to your app domain pointing to the ELB's DNS name.

Comment: Thanks for commenting: I didn't think of that, I'm testing with a CNAME right now.

Comment: `dig` reports the CNAME is active but I'm missing something in my target group.Or AWS is blocking my ALIAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ip might change so better use an other option such as **CNAME** or **A-record + Alias** (the latter might save you some money, if I remember correctly).

[image: Aws ELB A record + Alias]
(Route 53 setup)

Comment: I added a CNAME to the DNS of my Application Load Balancer and when I tried host app1.example.com on the subdomain I received  not found (nxdomain). I understand the roaming IP so I'll avoid that.

Comment: Have a look at the image I added - CNAME entries might take some time to propagate because of the DNS

Comment: I'm using an external registrar not Route 53. Do you think this might be my blocker?

Comment: As I said it takes time for DNS entries to propagate - maybe you just have to wait

Comment: Nods. I'm running a few tests with a route 53 domain, changes there for internal AWS jobs are usually instant and I can see an IP coming back straight away. I'll post my findings here.

Comment: Hi +ohlr, yes it does work and I intend to add a complete break down of what I did here so that other's can benefit from my work..... one task finished and another 10 appear :)